# TextureView transparent when windowIsTranslucent=true

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I have a video player in my application that uses a TextureView and a MediaPlayer. Everything works fine on most devices but according to Play store reviews, it seems that on low end devices only (YFANG tablets, WonderMedia MIDM-M803, Carrefour CT705,...) the TextureView displays nothing. After debugging, I found out that the windowIsTranslucent=true parameter in my theme is responsible for this. Is there any workaround ? How can I know that this property is not supported on a device ?

Any ideas ?

Thnaks

Comment: I continued investigating. Problem occurs on the following devices : GoClever TAB R974, WonderMedia midm-m803, Carrefour CTCT1001, YIFANG Next8P12. The common point between all these devices seems to be the GPU : MALI-400MP. Any way I could detect it and blacklist those devices ?

Comment: According to Wikipedia : The Mali 400 GPU in the Exynos 4210 SOC is one of the only, if not the only GPU powering Android devices, that does not support GL_RGB Framebuffer Objects (FBOs), only GL_RGBA. Could it be related ?

Comment: Ok so I am not the only one with the issue : https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/video-playback-not-working-texture

Comment: and http://community.arm.com/thread/4068 So my question is : As I need to blacklist this GPU, how can I detect the GPU of the device without instantiating a GLSurfaceView beforehand ? Thanks.

Comment: From android doc ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html ) => `TextureView can only be used in a hardware accelerated window. When rendered in software, TextureView will draw nothing.`